# how to fix CSRF error in django python?

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error while i enter the submit button in login form
Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure: CSRF token missing or incorrect.

---

login.html

```
<form method="post" action="/index/">{% csrf_token %}
    <table border="0">
        <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td></td></tr>
        <tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/home" />
</form>
```

---

views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    # Like before, obtain the context for the user's request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # If the request is a HTTP POST, try to pull out the relevant information.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Gather the username and password provided by the user.
        # This information is obtained from the login form.
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        # Use Django's machinery to attempt to see if the username/password
        # combination is valid - a User object is returned if it is.
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        # If we have a User object, the details are correct.
        # If None (Python's way of representing the absence of a value), no user
        # with matching credentials was found.
        if user:
            # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
            if user.is_active:
                # If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
                # We'll send the user back to the homepage.
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
            else:
                # An inactive account was used - no logging in!
                return HttpResponse("Your Rango account is disabled.")
        else:
            # Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

    # The request is not a HTTP POST, so display the login form.
    # This scenario would most likely be a HTTP GET.
    else:
        # No context variables to pass to the template system, hence the
        # blank dictionary object...

        return render_to_response('login/login.html', {}, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Did you follow any of the advice given on that error page? It has a full explanation of the possible causes and solutions.

Comment: i checked my code based on that instructions...still i cant able to fix...

Comment: Then you need to show your view and the relevant part of the template. We can't possibly guess what's wrong with your code without seeing it.

Comment: i shared my html and views code....please refer and send the solution to fix it...

Comment: You should *edit your question* and add them there, not post them as answers, because they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

When you POST data from a HTML form in Django, and have CSRF enabled, you need to include a [token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it) in the form:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

[Reference docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/).

Comment: <form id="login_form" method="post" action="/index/">
              {% csrf_token %}
               Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="30" />
              <br /><br />
               Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="30" />
              <br /><br />

              <input type="submit" value="submit" />
           </form>

Answer (score 0):

Add csrf token inside the form

```
<form id="login_form">{% csrf_token %}</form>
```